# jQuery click function only works after the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a landing page with an input button based on a form. The user adds the email in the form and through the input, downloads our catalog. I'm using jQuery Validate to validate the form field. In case the user places a valid email, the download of the PDF starts and a lightbox with a message appears. My problem is that the lightbox is only appearing after the second click.

Here is the form HTML:

```
<form id="formmail" action="sendmail.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="input">
        <label for="i-email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="news" id="news">
        <label for="i-news">Checkbox email</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="btn">
        <div id="test" href="javascript:;">
            <input type="submit" value="Download PDF"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="hidden-content">
            <p>Thank you</p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is the JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#formmail').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $("#test").on('click', function() {
        $.fancybox.open({
          src: '#hidden-content',
          type: 'inline',
          opts: {
            afterShow: function(instance, current) {
              console.info('done!');
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: the click is attached on first form submit... and appears in second

Comment: You are adding the click event at the wrong point in time.

Comment: Yea Moose is right. Don't add the click event when the form is submitted. Attach the event before that. It only works the second time because the first time is when you are attaching the click event, then the second time it attaches a new click event and fires the first one attached. Each subsequent click will add a new event and download amountOfClicks - 1 catalogs.

Comment: see the flow..you are adding the click function to div (which should be ideally submit button) also the click binding is done inside the validate functions submit handler which should be outside..so in simple terms on form validation toggle submit button and put its click handler outside (in document.ready(function(){//here}))

Comment: I don't think you need the click handler at all. Just display the lightbox in the submit handler, since that runs when you click the submit button.

Comment: Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are binding a listener after a submit callback, then it will be available only on the second click for sure.

I would do it differently

```
<script>
    function lightBox() {
        $.fancybox.open({
            src: '#hidden-content',
            type: 'inline',
            opts: {
                afterShow: function (instance, current) {
                    console.info('done!');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#formmail').validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                lightBox();
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#formmail').validate({
       submitHandler: function(form) {
         $("#test").on('click', function() {
           $.fancybox.open({
              src  : '#hidden-content',
              type : 'inline',
              opts : {
                afterShow : function( instance, current ) {
                console.info('done!');
              }
            }
         });

      });
      $("#test").trigger("click");
     }
   }) 
});
```

Comment: Why try this? What did you change? What was wrong? What does this fix / change?

Answer (score 0):

submitHandler handles the onclick event of input[type='submit'] itself.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#formmail').validate({
               submitHandler: function(form) {
                 //comment below line 
                 //$("#test").on('click', function() {
                   $.fancybox.open({
                      src  : '#hidden-content',
                      type : 'inline',
                      opts : {
                        afterShow : function( instance, current ) {
                        console.info('done!');
                      }
                    }
                 });

              //});
             }
           }) 
        });
```